# Define FlatButton setOnClickListener in ADT

Tags: java, android, android-layout, github

I am using [GitHub](https://github.com/eluleci/FlatUI) FlatUI classes for my application UI. I have successfully generated my layout with `FlatButtons` and now I want to set listener for these buttons. As mentioned in FlatUI sample code, I define my buttons in activity for example as :

```
flatButtons.add((FlatButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonCat));
```

And of course I have declared an array for all `FlatButtons` as :

```
private ArrayList<FlatButton> flatButtons = new ArrayList<FlatButton>();
```

My question is how I can set listener for this button? `buttonCat` is the `button id` of my FlatButton in xml Layout, so I guess I should define a new `FlatButton` somewhere in my activity class and refer `buttonCat` to that. But how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FlatButton button = (FlatButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonCat);
button.setOnClickListener(your_listener_here);
```